# How to add debounce time for list of input tags in reactive form angular 9 and detect which input tag getting type?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have a list of inputs using ngFor + input  I am displaying it as below

```
    <div*ngFor="let esControl of extraServicesControls.controls; let i = index; last as isLast; first as isFirst" [formGroup]="esControl">
<input
        type="number"
        name=""
        id=""
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
        aria-label="Enter insured amount"
        [value]="
          esControl.value.specialService?.inputParameters &&
          (esControl.value.specialService?.inputParameters)[0]?.value
        "
        (keyup)="valuechangeInput($event.target.value, esControl.value.specialService)"
      />
</div>
```

How to call API on each input in list with debounce time of 1000 ms when type  letter any input

Answer (score 1):

For this issue I am suggesting to use angular reactive forms.

In order to user Angular reactive forms

Import reactive forms module to your module

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the ts file create a new formGroup
import { debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
  this.form= this.fb.group({
    insertAmount: ''
  });

  //Then subscribe for valuechange
  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((val)=>{
     there is a new value for the input. Check logic here
   })
}
```

In this code the 500 means the amount of ms the stream has to wait before emitting a new value. In the mean time all the new value will be discarded.

More detail about reactive forms:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
More detail about RXJS debounceTime operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime

The reactive form is a pretty good kind of approach to achieve such debounceTime functionality.

The simpler approach is similar to what you did

html

```
<input
        type="number"
        name=""
        id=""
        class="form-control form-control-sm"
        aria-label="Enter insured amount"
        [value]="
          esControl.value.specialService?.inputParameters &&
          (esControl.value.specialService?.inputParameters)[0]?.value
        "
        (keyup)="valuechangeInput($event.target.value,i)"
      />
</div>
```

.ts

```
import {Replaysubject} from "rxjs"

private inputValue: Replaysubject<string[]>= new Replaysubject()
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
     this.inputValue.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((val)=>{
         there is a new value for the input. Check logic here
       })
}

valuechangeInput(value:string,index:number){
 this.inputValue.next({value,index});
}
```

Comment: what is this.inputValue ?

Comment: how to identify from a list of <input> which one currently typing?

Comment: Inputvalue is a Replaysubject which stores the value for each input in the list. I forgot to add to the html but you can add the function parameter the index of the ngfor